# Web URL load time in web view react native - how to check?

Tags: performance, react-native, webview, page-load-time

How to find out the load time of a url in React native web view?

Comment: Just one time?  Use https://www.webpagetest.org

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it in this way -

1. I am recording the onLoadStart time .
2. Then I am recording the onLoadEnd time.
3. And getting the differnce between the both of them.

> ```
> <WebView
>         source={{
>           uri,
>         }}
>         ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}
>         style={{ marginTop: 0, flex: 1 }}
>         onLoadStart={() => {
>           this.setState({ onLoadStartTime: Date.now() });
>         }}
>         onLoadEnd={() => {
>           var startTime = this.state.onLoadStartTime;
>           console.log('I am within onLoadEnd start time is, end tme is, time to load web page is', startTime, Date.now(), startTime - Date.now());
>         }}
>       />
> ```

Comment: I've had issues with this approach where onLoadEnd happens so quickly after onLoadStart that the setState hasn't updated, giving the wrong result.

Comment: you can try posting message to react-native app and calculate the time taken to load.
window.postMessage